# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'authDetails.access_token') while i

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the following error in my controller:

`angular.module('bcpBackOffice').controller('assetsCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$log', '$filter', '$compile', 'ApplicationConfig', '$mdDialog', 'RoomManagerFactory'`,

The error is showing for the variable `authDetails.access_token` in my controller.

**Here is my controller**

```
'use strict';
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name bcpBackOffice.controller:assetsCtrl
 * @description
 * # assetsCtrl
 * Controller of the bcpBackOffice
 */
angular.module('bcpBackOffice').controller('assetsCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$log', '$filter', '$compile', 'ApplicationConfig', '$mdDialog', 'RoomManagerFactory',
    'RoomService', 'DataService', 'RoomServicesVO', 'RoomPricingVO','BcpBase64ImageDataEncodedMultipartFileVO','ImagePath','RoomVO','ImageFileExtensionPattern', assetsCtrl]);


function assetsCtrl($scope, $state, $log, $filter, $compile, ApplicationConfig, $mdDialog, RoomManagerFactory, RoomService, DataService,
                    RoomServicesVO, RoomPricingVO, BcpBase64ImageDataEncodedMultipartFileVO, ImagePath, RoomVO, ImageFileExtensionPattern) {

// Variable definition
  var authDetails = ApplicationConfig.loggedInUserData.authDetails;
  var accessToken = authDetails.access_token;
  $scope.selectedTabIndex = 0;
  $scope.masterData = "";
  $scope.roomAttributes = [];
  $scope.roomServiceRateUnits = [];
  $scope.roomServices = [];
  $scope.dayHours = null;
  $scope.propertyId = ApplicationConfig.loggedInUserData.propertyId;
  $scope.rooms = [];
  $scope.populateMasterAttributeData = [];
  $scope.attributeValue = [];
  $scope.assetServices = new RoomServicesVO();
  $scope.editAssetServicesFlag = false;
  $scope.editAssetServicesIndex = '';
  $scope.imageRoomPicturesPath = ImagePath.RoomImagePicturePath;
  $scope.imageFloorPlanPath = ImagePath.RoomImageFloorPlanPath;
  $scope.validateUploadedFile = validateUploadedFile;
  $scope.assetsFromDateContainer = {};

  $scope.weekdaySlot = [];
  var weekdayPricingVO = new RoomPricingVO();
  weekdayPricingVO.slotType = 'WEEKDAY';
  $scope.weekdaySlot.push(weekdayPricingVO);

  $scope.weekendSlot = [];
  var weekendPricingVO = new RoomPricingVO();
  weekendPricingVO.slotType = 'WEEKEND';
  $scope.weekendSlot.push(weekendPricingVO);

  // Function definition
  $scope.increaseCounter = increaseCounter;
  $scope.decreaseCounter = decreaseCounter;
  $scope.loadDataForAssets = loadDataForAssets;
  $scope.addWeekdaySlot = addWeekdaySlot;
  $scope.addWeekendSlot = addWeekendSlot;
  $scope.deleteWeekdaySlot = deleteWeekdaySlot;
  $scope.deleteWeekendSlot = deleteWeekendSlot;
  $scope.addInclusiveServices = addInclusiveServices;
  $scope.closePopup = closePopup;
  $scope.saveInclusiveServices = saveInclusiveServices;
  $scope.getAssetsMasterData = getAssetsMasterData;
  $scope.switchToAssetsServiceTab = switchToAssetsServiceTab;
  $scope.saveRoomData = saveRoomData;
  $scope.getDayHours = getDayHours;
  $scope.addAdditionalServicesToRoom = addAdditionalServicesToRoom;
  $scope.populateAttributeData = populateAttributeData;
  $scope.getAllAssetsOfProperty = getAllAssetsOfProperty;
  $scope.setWorkingHoursToTime = setWorkingHoursToTime;
  $scope.disabledToDate = disabledToDate;
  $scope.validatePricingSlot = validatePricingSlot;
  $scope.editAssetService = editAssetService;
  $scope.deleteAssetService = deleteAssetService;
  $scope.reloadAssetServiceVO = reloadAssetServiceVO;
  $scope.uploadFloorPlan = uploadFloorPlan;
  $scope.uploadRoomImage = uploadRoomImage;
  $scope.imagesDataParser = imagesDataParser;

  /**
   * RoomVO Object Contains Data.
   */
  $scope.roomVO = RoomManagerFactory.retrieveInstance();
  $scope.roomServicesVO = new RoomServicesVO();
  $scope.roomPricingVO = new RoomPricingVO();


  /**
   * Save Room Data.(create new Asset.)
   */
  function saveRoomData() {
    $scope.roomVO.availableFromDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.assetsFromDateContainer.availableFromDate), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    $log.debug($scope.roomVO);
    if (typeof $scope.roomVO.roomType == "string" || $scope.roomVO.roomType instanceof String) {
      $scope.roomVO.roomType = JSON.parse($scope.roomVO.roomType);
    }
    addWeekdayAndWeekendSlotToAsset();
    RoomService.createRoomOfProperty($scope.roomVO, $scope.propertyId, accessToken).then(function (response) {
      $scope.rooms.push(response.data);
      $scope.roomVO = new RoomVO();
      $state.go('template.' + ApplicationConfig.urlBasedOnUserRole + '.assets.show-assets');
    },function(error){
      $log.error(error);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Add Additional Services to Room.
   */
  function addAdditionalServicesToRoom() {
    $scope.roomServicesVO = $scope.assetServices;
    if($scope.editAssetServicesFlag == true){
      $scope.roomVO.editRoomServices($scope.editAssetServicesIndex,$scope.roomServicesVO);
    }
    else {
      $scope.roomVO.addRoomServices($scope.roomServicesVO);
    }
    $scope.editAssetServicesFlag = false;
    $scope.assetServices = new RoomServicesVO();
    return true;
  }

  function getDayHours() {
    DataService.getDayHoursFromJson().then(function (response) {
      $scope.dayHours = response.data;
    });
  }

  function setWorkingHoursToTime(fromTime) {
    angular.forEach($scope.dayHours, function (dayHour, index) {
      if (fromTime == dayHour.value) {
        $scope.totimeIndex = index;
      }
    });
  }

  function reloadAssetServiceVO(){
    $scope.editAssetServicesFlag = false;
    $scope.assetServices = new RoomServicesVO();
  }

   function editAssetService(index){
     $scope.editAssetServicesFlag = true;
     $scope.editAssetServicesIndex = index;
     $scope.roomServicesVO = $scope.roomVO.roomServices[index];
     angular.copy($scope.roomServicesVO,  $scope.assetServices);
   }

   function deleteAssetService(index){
     $scope.roomVO.roomServices.splice(index,1);
  }

  function disabledToDate(fromTime, index, dayType) {
    var selectOptions;
    if (dayType == 'weekday') {
      selectOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('toTimeSelectWeekday_' + index)[0].options;
    }
    if (dayType == 'weekend') {
      selectOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('toTimeSelectWeekend_' + index)[0].options;
    }
    if (selectOptions.length > 0) {
      angular.forEach(selectOptions, function (selectOption) {
        selectOption.removeAttribute('disabled');
        var value = $filter('date')(selectOption.value, 'HH:mm:ss');
        var fromTimeFilter = $filter('date')(fromTime, 'HH:mm:ss');
        console.log(value-fromTimeFilter);

        if (value <= fromTimeFilter) {
          selectOption.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    }

  }

  /**
   * get master data while adding new assets
   */
  function getAssetsMasterData() {
    switchToAssetsServiceTab(0);
    var masterDataPromise = RoomService.getMasterDataOfRoom(accessToken);
    masterDataPromise.then(function (promise) {
      $scope.masterData = promise.data;
      //$scope.roomAttributes = $scope.masterData.roomAttributes;
      angular.copy($scope.masterData.roomAttributes, $scope.roomAttributes);
      angular.copy($scope.masterData.roomServiceRateUnits, $scope.roomServiceRateUnits);
      angular.copy($scope.masterData.roomServices, $scope.roomServices);
      $scope.attributeValue = [];
      populateAttributeData();
      $log.debug($scope.masterData.roomAttributes);
      $state.go('template.' + ApplicationConfig.urlBasedOnUserRole + '.assets.add-asset');
    });
  }

  function getAllAssetsOfProperty() {
    RoomService.getAllRoomsOfProperty(accessToken, $scope.propertyId).then(function (response) {
      $scope.rooms = response.data;
    });
  }

  function populateAttributeData() {
    $scope.populateMasterAttributeData = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.roomAttributes, function (attributeObject) {

      if (typeof attributeObject.value == "string" || attributeObject.value instanceof String) {
        var parsedAttributeValue = JSON.parse(attributeObject.value);
      } else {
        var parsedAttributeValue = attributeObject.value;
      }
      angular.forEach(parsedAttributeValue, function (attribute) {
        var tempAttributeObject = {};
        tempAttributeObject.id = attributeObject.id;
        tempAttributeObject.label = attribute;
        tempAttributeObject.checked = false;
        $scope.populateMasterAttributeData.push(tempAttributeObject);
      });
    }, $scope.populateMasterAttributeData);
  }

  /**
   * load the data after loading the page for Assets Page
   */
  function loadDataForAssets() {
    $scope.assetsFromDateContainer.availableFromDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    $scope.roomVO.guestCapacity = 1;
    $scope.roomVO.minimumBookingHours = 1;
  }

  /**
   * Increase counter value on click on item/element
   * @param value
   */
  function increaseCounter(value) {
    var countEle = document.getElementById(value);
    countEle.value = +countEle.value + 1;
    if (value == "countFld") {
      $scope.roomVO.guestCapacity = countEle.value;
    } else {
      if (value == "countFld2") {
        $scope.roomVO.minimumBookingHours = countEle.value;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Decrease counter value on click on item/element
   * @param value
   */
  function decreaseCounter(value) {
    var countEle = document.getElementById(value);
    if (countEle.value > 1) {
      countEle.value = countEle.value - 1;
      if (value == "countFld") {
        $scope.roomVO.guestCapacity = countEle.value;
      } else {
        if (value == "countFld2") {
          $scope.roomVO.minimumBookingHours = countEle.value;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
    }
  }

  /**
   * add time slot for weekday
   */
  function addWeekdaySlot() {
    var roomPricingVO = new RoomPricingVO();
    roomPricingVO.slotType = 'WEEKDAY';
    $scope.weekdaySlot.push(roomPricingVO);
    var currentIndex = ($scope.weekdaySlot.length - 1);

    var weekdaytbl = document.getElementById("weekdaySlotsTbl");
    var lasti = weekdaytbl.rows.length;
    var row = weekdaytbl.insertRow(lasti);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.setAttribute("style", "width:80px;");

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.setAttribute("style", "width:80px;");
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

    $log.debug($scope.weekdaySlot.length - 1);
    var formTimeModel = "weekdaySlot[" + currentIndex + "].fromTime";
    var toTimeModel = "weekdaySlot[" + currentIndex + "].toTime";
    var rateModel = "weekdaySlot[" + currentIndex + "].rate";

    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("weekdays_fromTime").innerHTML;
    cell1.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute("ng-model", formTimeModel);
    var disabledToDateFunction = 'disabledToDate(weekdaySlot[' + currentIndex + '].fromTime,' + currentIndex + ',\'weekday\')';
    cell1.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute("ng-change", disabledToDateFunction);


    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("weekdays_toTime").innerHTML;
    cell2.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute("ng-model", toTimeModel);
    cell2.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute("class", cell2.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].getAttribute("class") + ' toTimeSelectWeekday_' + currentIndex);

    cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("weekdays_price").innerHTML;
    cell3.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setAttribute("ng-model", rateModel);

    var deleteFunction = 'deleteWeekdaySlot($event,' + currentIndex + ')';
    cell4.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:;' data-ng-click = " + deleteFunction + "><img src='assets/images/icons/close_icon.png'></a>";

    disabledToDate($scope.weekdaySlot[currentIndex].fromTime, currentIndex,'weekday');
    $compile($(row).contents())($scope);
  }

  /**
   *  add time slot for weekend
   */
  function addWeekendSlot() {
    var roomPricingVO = new RoomPricingVO();
    roomPricingVO.slotType = 'WEEKEND';
    $scope.weekendSlot.push(roomPricingVO);

    var currentIndex = ($scope.weekendSlot.length - 1);

    var weekdaytbl = document.getElementById("weekendSlotsTbl");
    var lasti = weekdaytbl.rows.length;
    var row = weekdaytbl.insertRow(lasti);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.setAttribute("style", "width:80px;");

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.setAttribute("style", "width:80px;");
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

    var formTimeModel = "weekendSlot[" + currentIndex + "].fromTime";
    var toTimeModel = "weekendSlot[" + currentIndex + "].toTime";
    var rateModel = "weekendSlot[" + currentIndex + "].rate";

    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("weekdays_fromTime").innerHTML;
    cell1.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute("ng-model", formTimeModel);
    var disabledToDateFunction = 'disabledToDate(weekendSlot[' + currentIndex + '].fromTime,' + currentIndex + ',\'weekend\')';
    cell1.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute("ng-change", disabledToDateFunction);

    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("weekdays_toTime").innerHTML;
    cell2.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute("ng-model", toTimeModel);
    cell2.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute("class", cell2.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].getAttribute("class") + ' toTimeSelectWeekend_' + currentIndex);

    cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("weekdays_price").innerHTML;
    cell3.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setAttribute("ng-model", rateModel);

    var deleteFunction = 'deleteWeekendSlot($event,' + currentIndex + ')';
    cell4.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:;'  data-ng-click = " + deleteFunction + "><img src='assets/images/icons/close_icon.png'></a>";

    disabledToDate($scope.weekendSlot[currentIndex].fromTime, currentIndex, 'weekend');
    $compile($(row).contents())($scope);
  }

  function addWeekdayAndWeekendSlotToAsset() {
    var mergedWeekdayWeekendPricing = [];
    mergedWeekdayWeekendPricing = $scope.weekdaySlot.concat($scope.weekendSlot);
    $scope.roomVO.roomPricings = mergedWeekdayWeekendPricing;
  }

  /**
   * delete weekday slots
   * @param $event
   */
  function deleteWeekdaySlot($event, currentIndex) {
    var index = $event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("weekdaySlotsTbl").deleteRow(index);
    delete($scope.weekdaySlot[currentIndex]);
  }

  /**
   * delete weekend slots
   * @param $event
   */
  function deleteWeekendSlot($event, currentIndex) {
    var index = $event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("weekendSlotsTbl").deleteRow(index);
    delete($scope.weekendSlot[currentIndex]);
  }

  /**
   * add Inclusive Services for Assets popup
   */
  function addInclusiveServices() {
    $mdDialog.show({
      templateUrl: 'app/templates/views/' + ApplicationConfig.urlBasedOnUserRole + '/fragments/add-inclusive-assets-services.html',
      scope: $scope,
      preserveScope: true,
      overlay: true,
      clickOutsideToClose: false,
      parent:angular.element('#addInclusiveServices')
    });
  }

  /**
   * Save added inclusive services for Assets
   */
  function saveInclusiveServices() {
    addAttributeToAsset();
    $mdDialog.hide();
  }

  function addAttributeToAsset() {
    $scope.attributeValue = [];
    $scope.roomVO.roomAttributes = $scope.masterData.roomAttributes;
    $log.debug($scope.populateMasterAttributeData);
    if (typeof $scope.roomVO.roomAttributes == "string" || $scope.roomVO.roomAttributes instanceof String) {
      $scope.roomVO.roomAttributes = JSON.parse($scope.roomVO.roomAttributes);
    }
    if ($scope.roomVO.roomAttributes.length != 0) {
      angular.forEach($scope.roomVO.roomAttributes, function (roomAttribute) {
        var filteredSelectedAttr = $filter('filter')($scope.populateMasterAttributeData, function (populateMasterAttributeData) {
          return ((roomAttribute.id == populateMasterAttributeData.id)&&(populateMasterAttributeData.checked == true));
        });

        var tempAttributeValueArray = [];
        angular.forEach(filteredSelectedAttr, function (filteredAttributeLabel) {
          tempAttributeValueArray.push(filteredAttributeLabel.label);
          $scope.attributeValue.push(filteredAttributeLabel.label);
        });
        roomAttribute.value = tempAttributeValueArray;
      });
    }
    $scope.roomVO.roomAttributes = JSON.stringify($scope.roomVO.roomAttributes);
  }

  /**
   * close the popup window
   */
  function closePopup() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  }

  /**
   * after adding new asset switch to next tab
   * to add assets service
   * @param index
   */
  function switchToAssetsServiceTab(index) {
    $scope.selectedTabIndex = index;
  }

  function validatePricingSlot(){
    createDummyTimeSlots();
    //var sortByStartTime = $filter('orderBy')($scope.weekdaySlot, expression, comparator);
    return false;
  }

  function createDummyTimeSlots(){
    var listOfHours =  $filter('getValueArrayOfKey')($scope.dayHours)('value');
    var operableHours = $filter('filter')(listOfHours, function(hour){
      return (hour >= $scope.roomVO.operableHoursStartTime && hour <= $scope.roomVO.operableHoursEndTime);
    });

    var sortedByFromTimeAndToTime = $filter('orderBy')($scope.weekdaySlot, ['fromTime', 'toTime']);
    angular.forEach(sortedByFromTimeAndToTime, function(sortedObject){
      angular.forEach(operableHours, function(hour, index){
        if(hour >= sortedObject.fromTime && hour <= sortedObject.toTime){
          operableHours.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log("+++++++++++++++++operableHours++++++++++++++++++++");
    console.log(operableHours);
  }

  function uploadFloorPlan(files) {
    if(validateUploadedFile()) {
      var roomFloorPlanVO = new BcpBase64ImageDataEncodedMultipartFileVO().getRoomFloorPlanVO();
      roomFloorPlanVO.originalFileName = files[0].name;
      roomFloorPlanVO.size = files[0].size;
      roomFloorPlanVO.contentType = files[0].type;
      if (files && files[0]) {
        setImageBase64ToBase64VO(roomFloorPlanVO, files[0]);
      }
      $scope.roomVO.floorPlanImageData = roomFloorPlanVO;
      $log.debug($scope.roomVO);
    }
  }

  function uploadRoomImage(files) {
    if (validateUploadedFile()) {
      console.log(files);
      angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
        var roomImageVO = new BcpBase64ImageDataEncodedMultipartFileVO().getRoomImageVO();
        roomImageVO.originalFileName = file.name;
        roomImageVO.size = file.size;
        roomImageVO.contentType = file.type;
        if (files && files[0]) {
          setImageBase64ToBase64VO(roomImageVO, file);
        }
        $scope.roomVO.addRoomImageData(roomImageVO);
      });
      $log.debug($scope.roomVO);
    }
  }

  function setImageBase64ToBase64VO(roomFloorPlanAndImageDataVO, file) {
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function (e) {
      roomFloorPlanAndImageDataVO.base64EncodedImageData = e.target.result;
    };
    FR.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  function imagesDataParser(roomImages, index){
    if (typeof roomImages == "string" || roomImages instanceof String) {
      $scope.rooms[index].images = JSON.parse(roomImages);
    }
  }

  function validateUploadedFile() {
    var allowedFiles = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png"];
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("myfile");
    var myPicture = document.getElementById("myPicture");
    var lblError = document.getElementById("lblError");
    var errorMyPicture = document.getElementById("errorMyPicture");
    if (fileUpload.files.length > 0) {
      if (!(ImageFileExtensionPattern).test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
        lblError.innerHTML = "Please upload files having extensions: <b>" + allowedFiles.join(', ') + "</b> only.";
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (myPicture.files.length > 0) {
      var flag = false;
      for(var readFile = 0; readFile < myPicture.files.length;readFile ++) {
        if (!(ImageFileExtensionPattern).test(myPicture.files[readFile].name.toLowerCase())) {
          errorMyPicture.innerHTML = "Please upload files having extensions: <b>" + allowedFiles.join(', ') + "</b> only.";
          flag = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(flag){return false;}
      if (myPicture.files.length > 5) {
        errorMyPicture.innerHTML = "Oops!! You can upload max 5 files";
        return false;
      }
    }
    lblError.innerHTML = "";
    errorMyPicture.innerHTML = "";
    return true;
  }

  // called function on load
  $scope.getDayHours();
  $scope.getAllAssetsOfProperty();
}



**Here is my test case :**
'use strict';

describe('Controller: assetsCtrl', function () {

  beforeEach(module('bcpBackOffice'));
  beforeEach(module('BcpUIServices'));
  beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

  var assetsCtrl,
    state,
    log,
    filter,
    compile,
    ApplicationConfig,
    mdDialog,
    RoomManagerFactory,
    RoomService,
    DataService,
    RoomServicesVO,
    RoomPricingVO,
    $rootScope,
    scope,
    $httpBackend;


  //Mock Data
  var mockDayHours= [{
    "label": "06:00 AM",
    "value": "06:00:00"
  },
    {
    "label": "07:00 AM",
    "value": "07:00:00"
  }];

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller, _$state_, _$log_, _$filter_, _$compile_, _ApplicationConfig_, _$mdDialog_, _RoomManagerFactory_, _RoomService_, _DataService_,
                             _RoomServicesVO_, _RoomPricingVO_, _$httpBackend_){
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    state = _$state_;
    log = _$log_;
    filter = _$filter_;
    compile = _$compile_;
    ApplicationConfig = _ApplicationConfig_;
    mdDialog = _$mdDialog_;
    RoomManagerFactory = _RoomManagerFactory_;
    RoomService = _RoomService_;
    DataService = _DataService_;
    RoomServicesVO = _RoomServicesVO_;
    RoomPricingVO = _RoomPricingVO_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    assetsCtrl = $controller('assetsCtrl', {
      $scope:scope,
      $state:state,
      $log:log,
      $filter:filter,
      $compile:compile,
      ApplicationConfig:ApplicationConfig,
      $mdDialog:mdDialog,
      RoomManagerFactory:RoomManagerFactory,
      RoomService:RoomService,
      DataService:DataService,
      RoomServicesVO:RoomServicesVO,
      RoomPricingVO:RoomPricingVO
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(function(){
    ApplicationConfig.loggedInUserData.authDetails = {
      access_token: "0e45e276-89ff-403f-8e02-7f85a41c2d26",
      token_type: "bearer",
      refresh_token: "ce872f46-5877-4266-9a0e-5199b63ac247",
      expires_in: 10430,
      scope: "read write"
    };
  $httpBackend.whenGET("app/mock_data/dayHours.json").respond(mockDayHours);
  });

  beforeEach(function(){
    $rootScope.$digest();
  });

  it('should get day hours', function(){
    scope.getDayHours();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(scope.dayHours).toBe(mockDayHours);
  });
```

Comment: Obviously `authDetails` is undefined, so it's probably something wrong with `ApplicationConfig.loggedInUserData.authDetails` - What happens inside this `ApplicationConfig.loggedInUserData` config? Are you sure it point to the correct details?

Comment: I am mocking "ApplicationConfig.loggedInUserData.authDetails" in my test case which is required for var authDetails in controller file.

ApplicationConfig is angular.value in my project, a global object which will store data in key-value pair